# Checking NA values and difference

Tags: r

What is the difference between `sum(is.na(bollywood), T)` and `sum(is.na(bollywood))`?

I have tried both of these but they are giving different output and I'm not sure of the reason.

Answer (score 1):

The `T` at the end is for `na.rm` argument.  It is better to spell out the `TRUE` instead of `T` as it is not possible to assign `TRUE` as object name while `T` can be assigned and this can lead to some buggy situations

```
sum(is.na(bollywood, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Here, there is no need for `na.rm` as `is.na` is returning only TRUE/FALSE as output depending on whether the object element have `NA` or not.  `sum` will give the sum of all TRUE elements (`TRUE` - 1, `FALSE` - 0)

---

Using a small reproducible example

```
bollywood <- c('a', 'b', NA, 'd',  NA)
is.na(bollywood)
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

here, there are two  `NA`s, so `sum` returns 2

```
sum(is.na(bollywood))
#[1] 2
```

Now, we define an object `T`

```
T <- 5
sum(is.na(bollywood), T)
#[1] 7
```

So, here, it adds the 2 with T value of 5

instead, it should be

```
sum(is.na(bollywood), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 2
```

As noted above, `na.rm` is not at all needed. If we check the documentation of `?sum`, usage is

```
sum(..., na.rm = FALSE)
```

i.e. `...` can take multiple arguments, so, the `is.na(bollywood)` would be the first argument, the `T` (object created) second argument, and so on